# Is this correct $\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{2^n}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k - 1)$?

Tags: integration, gamma-function

This [WolframAlpha Gamma Function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BGamma%5Bn%2B1%2F2%5D%2C%20%7Bn%2C%205%7D%5D) displays

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},\frac{3\sqrt{\pi}}{4},\frac{15\sqrt{\pi}}{8},\frac{105\sqrt{\pi}}{16},
\frac{945\sqrt{\pi}}{32},
\frac{10395\sqrt{\pi}}{64}
$$

Notice denominators are $2^n$ and numerators are $1,3,15,105,954,10395$. Searching OEIS found [A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147).

So, the general pattern is

$$\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{2^n}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k - 1)$$

I'm very rusty with integration, so I wasn't sure how to verify that pattern.

Comment: Hint: no need for integration use $\Gamma(n+1/2)=(n-1/2)\Gamma(n-1/2)$

Comment: In other words, prove it by induction on $n$ using @RaymondManzoni's hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property

$$\Gamma(z+1)=z\Gamma(z)~~~\text{and}~~~\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$$

Let $z=n-\frac{1}2$, so we have

$$\Gamma(n+\frac{1}2)=(n-\frac{1}2)\Gamma(n-\frac{1}2)$$

Similarly,

$$\Gamma(n-\frac{1}2)=(n-\frac{3}2)\Gamma(n-\frac{3}2)$$

So we get a chain,

$$\Gamma(n+\frac{1}2)=(n-\frac{1}2)\cdot(n-\frac{3}2)\dots\frac{3}2\cdot \frac{1}2\cdot\Gamma(\frac{1}2)=\frac{(2n-1)\cdot (2n-3)\dots 2\cdot 1}{2^n}\sqrt\pi$$

Therefore,

$$\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} }{2^n}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n} (2k - 1)$$

Comment: Thanks. Seems more straight forward than solving $$\Gamma\left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)} e^{-t} \, dt$$